# Proper way to return a pointer to a `new` object from an Rcpp function

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Consider 1) a custom class with a potentially large memory print, and 2) a top-level function that performs some pre-processing, then creates and returns a new object of our custom class. To avoid unnecessary copying by value, the function allocates the object and returns a pointer to it instead.

Based on a [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947880/pass-a-c-object-as-a-pointer-an-reuse-in-another-function-in-rcpp), it seems that the proper way to return a pointer to a newly-created object is to wrap it with `Rcpp::XPtr<>`. However, R then sees it effectively as `externalptr`, and I am struggling to find the proper way to cast it with the modern `RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS` and `RCPP_MODULE` way of doing things.

The alternative is to return the raw pointer. But then I'm not 100% certain that the object memory gets properly cleaned up. I ran `valgrind` to test for memory leaks, and it didn't find any. However, who does the clean up? R?

**test.cpp**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// Custom class
class Double {
public:
  Double( double v ) : value(v) {}
  double square() {return value*value;}
private:
  double value;
};

// Make the class visible
RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(Double)

// Option 1: returning raw pointer
Double* makeDouble( double x ) {
  Double* pd = new Double(x);
  return pd;
}

// Option 2: returning XPtr<>
SEXP makeDouble2( double x ) {
  Double* pd = new Double(x);
  Rcpp::XPtr<Double> ptr(pd);
  return ptr;
}

RCPP_MODULE(double_cpp) {
  using namespace Rcpp;

  function( "makeDouble", &makeDouble );
  function( "makeDouble2", &makeDouble2 );

  class_<Double>("Double")
    .constructor<double>("Wraps a double")
    .method("square", &Double::square, "square of value")
    ;
}
```

**In R**

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("test.cpp")
d1 <- makeDouble(5.4)     # <-- who cleans this up???
# C++ object <0x56257d628e70> of class 'Double' <0x56257c69cf90>
d1$square()
# 29.16

d2 <- makeDouble2(2.3)
# <pointer: 0x56257d3c3cd0>
d2$square()
# Error in d2$square : object of type 'externalptr' is not subsettable
```

My question is whether `Rcpp::Xptr<>` is the proper way of returning pointers, and if so, how do I get R to see the result as `Double`, not `externalptr`? Alternatively, if returning a raw pointer doesn't cause memory issues, who cleans up the object that the function creates?

Comment: Yes, you probably want `Rcpp::XPtr` to create an external pointer from C++ code.  And you want to cast it do `double *` or whatever your payload is.  There should be examples here, at the Gallery, at GitHub...   Maybe with a motivated search you can find something close enough?

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel The cast really needs to be to `CustomClass*`. The real application is a custom data structure with no R equivalent and all interactions are done through the functionality exposed by the `RCPP_MODULE`. The closest match my motivated search found was a [post from 7 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12458161/300187), where it seems that I need to define a `template <> CustomClass* as()` converter. However, I am unclear on how it should interact with `RCPP_MODULE` and `RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS`, especially since I thought the latter already defined `wrap()` and `as()`.

Comment: Romain's post from that same thread is very helpful too, but unfortunately it highlights the usage of objects directly, rather than handling of pointers.

Comment: I know I have done similar stuff but now I not sure what the very best example this.  You can clearly setup a 'singleton' object and wrap as a module (RcppRedis); I think I have done what you describe at a prior job or two but I can't think of a good public example now.  Then again -- the various database wrappers and access package do that.  Not the smallest topic, so maybe start with a toy / mock implementation and build from there?

Comment: Using `RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS` and `RCPP_MODULE` is really the way to do it? I've never used or seen that before.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think it makes sense to look at the different approaches separately. This makes the distinction clearer. Note that this is quite similar to the discussion in the Rcpp Modules vignette.

When using `Rcpp::XPtr` you have your class and provide exported C++ functions for every method you want to expose:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// Custom class
class Double {
public:
    Double( double v ) : value(v) {}
    double square() {return value*value;}
private:
    double value;
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::XPtr<Double> makeDouble(double x) {
    Double* pd = new Double(x);
    Rcpp::XPtr<Double> ptr(pd);
    return ptr;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double squareDouble(Rcpp::XPtr<Double> x) {
    return x.get()->square();
}

/***R
(d2 <- makeDouble(5.4))
squareDouble(d2)
*/
```

Output:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('59384221/xptr.cpp')

> (d2 <- makeDouble(5.4))
<pointer: 0x560366699b50>

> squareDouble(d2)
[1] 29.16
```

Note that in R the object is only a "pointer". You could add an S4/RC/R6/... class on the R side if you want something nicer.

Wrapping the external pointer into a class on the R side is something you get for free by using Rcpp modules:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// Custom class
class Double {
public:
    Double( double v ) : value(v) {}
    double square() {return value*value;}
private:
    double value;
};

RCPP_MODULE(double_cpp) {
    using namespace Rcpp;

    class_<Double>("Double")
        .constructor<double>("Wraps a double")
        .method("square", &Double::square, "square of value")
    ;
}

/***R
(d1 <- new(Double, 5.4))
d1$square()
*/
```

Output:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('59384221/modules.cpp')

> (d1 <- new(Double, 5.4))
C++ object <0x560366452eb0> of class 'Double' <0x56036480f320>

> d1$square()
[1] 29.16
```

It is also supported to use a factory method instead of a constructor in C++ but with identical usage on the R side:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// Custom class
class Double {
public:
    Double( double v ) : value(v) {}
    double square() {return value*value;}
private:
    double value;
};

Double* makeDouble( double x ) {
    Double* pd = new Double(x);
    return pd;
}

RCPP_MODULE(double_cpp) {
    using namespace Rcpp;

    class_<Double>("Double")
        .factory<double>(makeDouble, "Wraps a double")
        .method("square", &Double::square, "square of value")
    ;
}

/***R
(d1 <- new(Double, 5.4))
d1$square()
*/
```

Output:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('59384221/modules-factory.cpp')

> (d1 <- new(Double, 5.4))
C++ object <0x5603665aab80> of class 'Double' <0x5603666eaae0>

> d1$square()
[1] 29.16
```

Finally, `RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS` comes in handy if you want to combine an R side factory function with Rcpp Modules, since this creates the `Rcpp::as` and `Rcpp::wrap` extensions needed to pass objects back an forth between R and C++. The factory could be exported via `function` as you did or using Rcpp Attributes, which I find more natural:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// Custom class
class Double {
public:
    Double( double v ) : value(v) {}
    double square() {return value*value;}
private:
    double value;
};

// Make the class visible
RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(Double)

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Double makeDouble( double x ) {
    Double d(x);
    return d;
}

RCPP_MODULE(double_cpp) {
    using namespace Rcpp;

    class_<Double>("Double")
        .method("square", &Double::square, "square of value")
    ;
}

/***R
(d1 <- makeDouble(5.4))
d1$square()
*/
```

Output:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('59384221/modules-expose.cpp')

> (d1 <- makeDouble(5.4))
C++ object <0x560366ebee10> of class 'Double' <0x560363d5f440>

> d1$square()
[1] 29.16
```

Concerning clean-up: Both `Rcpp::XPtr` and Rcpp Modules register a default finalizer that calls the object's destructor. You can also add a custom finalizer if needed.

I find it difficult to give a recommendation for one of these approaches. Maybe it is best to try each of them on some simple example and see what you find more natural to use.

Comment: Very nice stuff. You are on a roll here.

Comment: Thank you. This is extremely helpful! I think `factory` is the key connector piece I've been missing.

Comment: As a small follow up, do you happen to know if `function` also registers a finalizer, or is it only `factory `?

Comment: @ArtemSokolov AFAIK the default finalizer that calls the destructor is generated by `class_<T>` and is independent of how the object is created.

Comment: One of those rare excellent answers where I actually bother to log in and upvote.